# Upgrading sqlite on Centos 7

Tags: centos, sqlite

I'm installing a Django app on a Centos 7 server. The app uses Django 2.2, which requires SQLite 3.8.3 or newer. Centos comes with SQLite 3.7 from 2013.

When I compile SQLite 3 from sources and run `make install`, it installs the new SQLite in `/usr/local/bin`. Running `sqlite3 --version` shows version 3.30, as it should. However, Python keeps seeing the old version of SQLite.

Recompiling Python does not help. Turns out there's `/usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6` shared object that's used by Python. This shared object is not updated when compiling SQLite again, nor is a new shared object created (I ran `./configure --enable-shared`).

Other than downgrading to Django 2.1 or switching to a Debian based Linux I don't see any way out of this.